# How to remove ambiguity in following grammar?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, ambiguous-grammar

```
S -> Sa | SbSa | ε
```

I found a similar question but i don't understand : http://automatasteps.blogspot.co.id/2007/08/unambiguous-grammar.html

How do i change this to the unambiguous one?

My string is bbaaa

Comment: Your linked question is not similar; it's identical. So it would help if you said what you didn't understand, since it provides a precise answer to your question, and just repeating it here isn't going to help you.

Comment: I meant, he used an example for the answer and i don't understand how + could change to * in that example. Can i get the answer for my question, because he just put an example and it is totally different.

Comment: The answer to your question comes before the example. He provides precisely the unambiguous grammar corresponding to your ambiguous grammar, and a very brief explanation of how he derived it. Then he provides *another* example of making a *different* ambiguous grammar unambiguous, which you could either ignore or try to understand. (If you really want to learn about this stuff, trying to understand would be a good start.)